# Is there any way to run a script as a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there any way to run a script as a string in JavaScript like this?

```js
// core.jslib
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  myCallback: function (str, arg) {
    runScript(str, arg); // I want a function like this
  }
});
```

```html
// execute script
<script>
  var script = "function(str){ window.alert(UTF8ToString(str)); }";
  myCallback(script, "Hello, World");
</script>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to run a script in this way.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  You can, but there is (almost) always a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm using that function of UNITY. This is needed to send a message from C# to JavaScript.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

Comment: Yes, but _why_ do you need to send a sting containing function code?  Why can't you have the function (maybe inside an object) and use that?